# how to parse soap response in JSON Array in iOS

Tags: objective-c

how to parse soap response in JSON Array 
soap response string :-

NSString *string=@"http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/\" xmlns:xsi=\"http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance\" xmlns:xsd=\"http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema\">http://tempuri.org/\">[{\"rest_id\": 1, \"rest_name\": \"canteen 21\", \"rest_address\": \"janakpuri\",\"clientid\": 1, \"rest_lat\": \"28.619713\",\"rest_long\": \"77.088404}]";

```
NSData *webData = [string dataUsingEncoding:NSASCIIStringEncoding];
NSError *e = nil;
NSArray *jsonArray = [NSJSONSerialization JSONObjectWithData: webData options: NSJSONReadingAllowFragments error: &e];
```

Comment: With a JSON parser, of which there are several.  Except that the above isn't quite legal JSON.  The only legal JSON in there is the part after `tempuri.org^>`.

Comment: Wasnt the point of SOAP to not have to bother with serialization of transported values?

Maybe you want to use something else for your app.

Comment: @HotLicks string     NSString *string=@"<?xml version=\"1.0\" encoding=\"utf-8\"?><soap:Envelope xmlns:soap=\"http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/\" xmlns:xsi=\"http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance\" xmlns:xsd=\"http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema\"><soap:Body><getRestaurentResponse xmlns=\"http://tempuri.org/\"><getRestaurentResult>[{\"rest_id\": 1, \"rest_name\": \"canteen 21\", \"rest_address\": \"janakpuri\",\"clientid\": 1, \"rest_lat\": \"28.619713\",\"rest_long\": \"77.088404}]</getRestaurentResult></getRestaurentResponse></soap:Body></soap:Envelope>";

Comment: @Rakesh - The legal JSON begins after `<getRestaurantResult>`.

Comment: (You first need to parse the whole thing with an XML parser (which SOAP should do automatically), then parse the "getRestaurantResult" tag's text with a JSON parser.)  (And NSJSONSerialization is awkward to use for this -- SBJSON is probably a better choice.)

Answer (score 1):

Use NSJSONSerialization .

As per docs
You use the NSJSONSerialization class to convert JSON to Foundation objects and convert Foundation objects to JSON.

[{\"rest_id\": 1, \"rest_name\": \"canteen 21\", \"rest_address\": \"janakpuri\",\"clientid\": 1, \"rest_lat\": \"28.619713\",\"rest_long\": \"77.088404}]"

This part is json and it can be parsed so make the code to get this portion into a string and do the parsing

Comment: i have used NSJSONSerialization but result is null. NSArray *jsonArray = [NSJSONSerialization JSONObjectWithData: webData options: NSJSONReadingAllowFragments error: &e];

Comment: @Rakesh - Because it's not JSON.

Comment: how to parse this string any idea please help .

Comment: @Rakesh - Maybe an XML parser?